# Lambda expressions "x cannot be resolved to variable" error

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, compiler-errors

So I'm currently learning java and the problem lies within this example class: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/examples/Calculator.java

When I try to copy the code into eclipse(newest version, jdk 1.8, java compliance 1.7) it says that a can't be resolved to variable.
[image]

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change the Java compliance to 1.8, otherwise lambda expressions would not be understood by the compiler (lambda expressions were introduced in Java 8).

In Eclipse, Java 8 is supported starting version Luna.

Comment: But it doesn't  even show 1.8 in the selection, am I supposed to download something additionally?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: In About it says: "Version: Juno Service Release 2".

Comment: Java 8 support was introduced in version Luna (two releases newer).

Comment: I apologize then, I just downloaded the first version that was offered assuming it was newest. Thank you!